# Texmaker: how to stop internal pdf viewer from changing the zoom when switching between opened files

Tags: texmaker, viewers, zooming

I am using Texmaker as an editor.

When I switch from one opened file to another and then quick build, the internal pdf viewer's zoom setting changes from where I originally set it on the first file.  This is frustrating because I like to switch between files and copy/paste things from one file to another, and the default zoom setting is too small to be comfortable to read.  How do I set a zoom amount and then have this setting persist when switching between files?

Comment: I suggest to use an external  viewer. You can configure texmaker in this way. I use Linux and Okular and the configuration stays as is. Page number, zoom and Okular re-reads automatically.